# How can you correct the skewness of an Xarray Dataset efficiently

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, scipy, python-xarray

I am working on the CDS API and I'm interested to implement the best way in which I can first find out the skewness of a particular DataArray of an Xarray DataSet. And then apply any suitable transformation (such as box Cox ) on the same DataArray. Please note that the DataArray is in 2D format (longitude and latitude)

The problems are:

1. The scipy skew method provides the skewness of every element in the 2D array. I understand that ideally it should work like this but what I am looking for is a skew value of the whole 2D DataArray.
2. I want to apply box Cox and any other transformation available on the Xarray DataArray but they seem to only accept 1D arrays. How to implement the same for 2D or maybe higher dimensional arrays in the most efficient way?

What I'm currently trying to do is this:

```
import xarray as xr
import scipy.stats as stats

ds = xr.open_dataset("datasets.nc")
tp = ds['tp']

tp = stats.boxcox(tp)
```

What I expect is to have unskewed data after the transformation.
Is there a straight way to do it, like how I am trying to do? If not, what am I missing here?

If I try to do directly use boxcox on the dataarray 'tp', I get this error (reference of the 2nd point above):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-8-bbb0bad8d4d5> in <module>()
----> 1 tp_boxcox = stats.boxcox(tp)
      2 tp_boxcox

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/stats/morestats.py in boxcox(x, lmbda, alpha)
   1034     x = np.asarray(x)
   1035     if x.ndim != 1:
-> 1036         raise ValueError("Data must be 1-dimensional.")
   1037 
   1038     if x.size == 0:

ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional.
```

Comment: I think you want `.groupby(dim).map(func)`, but without a reproducible example, I'm not certain. Docs: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.groupby.DataArrayGroupBy.map.html#xarray.core.groupby.DataArrayGroupBy.map

Comment: what exactly should my function 'func' do?

Comment: I think `stats.boxcox` — but https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example